# Deriving Ito process with a drift from geometric Brownian motion.

Tags: brownian-motion

Please help me solve this question. Thank you.

Let the Geometric Brownian motion be:
$$
\frac{\Delta S}{S} = \mu \Delta t + \sigma \epsilon \sqrt{\Delta t}
$$

$\Delta S$ = change in stock price (s)

$\mu$ = expected rate of return

$\sigma$ = volatility of shock

$epsilon$ has standard normal N(0,1) distribution

$\sigma \epsilon \sqrt{\Delta t}$ = stochastic companion

i) Derive the Ito process with a drift for the above 
ii) Given that the option price at time $t$ is $f(s,t)$, derive the process with Ito's lemma. Give an example.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** Users typically shun a straight transcription of homework problems. Please try to augment your question with you efforts so far. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This depends very much on what level of rigour you're requiring. A 'formal' answer may be out of the scope of the course/notes you're reading. In this case the It\^o process would be the one satisfying the SDE
$$
dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t,
$$
i.e. $S_t = S_0 + \int_0^t \mu S_s ds + \int_0^t \sigma S_s dW_s$.